# Data Modeling for table in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a hypothetical table with the following information about cost of vehicles, and I am trying to model the data for storing into a `Expenses` collection in MongoDB:

| Category | Item | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Land** | **Car** | 1000 |
| **Land** | **Motorbike** | 500 |
| **Air** | **Plane** | 2000 |
| **Air** | **Others:** Rocket | 5000 |

One assumption for this use case is that the `Category`s and `Item`s are fixed fields in the table, while users will fill in the `Cost` for each specific `Item` in the table. Should there be other vehicles in the category, users will fill them under "Others".

Currently,  of 2 options to store the document:

Option 1 - as a nested object:

```
[
  {
    "category": "land",
    "items": [
      {"name": "Car", "cost": 1000},
      {"name": "Motorbike", "cost": 500},
    ]
  }
  {
    "category": "air",
    "items": [
      {"name": "Plane", "cost": 2000},
      {"name": "Others", remarks: "Rocket", "cost": 5000},
    ]
  }
]
```

Option 2 - as a flattened array, where the React application will map the array to render the data in the table:

```
[
  {"category": "land", "item": "car", "cost": 1000},
  {"category": "land", "item": "motorbike", "cost": 500},
  {"category": "air", "item": "plane", "cost": 2000},
  {"category": "air", "item": "others", "remarks": "rocket", "cost": 5000},
]
```

Was hoping to get any suggestions on which is a better approach, or if there is a better approach that you have in mind.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Option 1 is fine, as long as the `items` array is a finite and known size (it should not be a ever growing one). Another consideration is the size of the document limit of 16 MB. And, the following applies to both - that you are able to perform the CRUD operations efficiently as per your application needs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @prasad_! :) While users can add multiple `item`s (by adding new rows under "Others"), I don't foresee this to go beyond the 16 MB limit. Further, a consideration for option 2 is that my Front-end developer is using React Hook Form (https://react-hook-form.com/) and commented that it would be easier to store data in a flattened format. Therefore, would like to get some opinions on which would be better (or cleaner) approach as a schema design.